# duplicate case label in case 79-70

Tags: java, label, case

I have a duplicate case label in the following code. The java compiler is saying that I have a duplicate case label in case 79-70. I'm a new java programmer, so could you please explain what I did wrong using less java terminology?

```
public class Unit4Test2
 {
  public static void main( String [] args)
    {
      int test_Score = 80;
      int test_Score2 = 40;
      int Grade_Average = (test_Score + test_Score2) / 2 ;

     switch( Grade_Average )
  {
     case 100-90:
       System.out.println( " Your average test score is " + Grade_Average );
       System.out.println( "Your letter grade is an A." );
       break;
     case 89-80:
       System.out.println( " Your average test score is " + Grade_Average );
       System.out.println( "Your letter grade is a B." );
       break;
     case 79-70:
       System.out.println( " Your average test score is " + Grade_Average );
       System.out.println( "Your letter grade is a C." );
       break;     
     case 69-65:
       System.out.println( " Your average test score is " + Grade_Average );
       System.out.println( "Your letter grade is a D." );
       break;
     case 64-0:
       System.out.println( " Your average test score is " + Grade_Average );
       System.out.println( "Your letter grade is a F." );
       break;
    default:
    System.out.println( " Invalid test score. ");
    break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`79-70` is not treated as range but rather as simple subtraction and its value is `9`. Because you also wrote `89-80` and the value of that is also `9`, the compiler thinks you want to specify `9` twice.

To better structure this use `if` and `else if` rather than using a switch for this matter:

```java
if (Grade_Average > 100)
{
    System.out.println("Not possible, you got more than 100 points you cheater!");
}
else if (Grade_Average >= 90)
{
    System.out.println( " Your average test score is " + Grade_Average );
    System.out.println( "Your letter grade is an A." );
}
else if (Grade_Average >= 80)
{
    // do stuff
}
// moar stuff!!11!one!
else if (Grade_Average >= 0)
{
    System.out.println( " Your average test score is " + Grade_Average );
    System.out.println( "Your letter grade is a F." );
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Error! I cannot grade your score!");
}
```

This approach first checks if `Grade_Average` is greater than the first threshold, and if it is it prints the respective sentences. Next it checks the next threshold and if if is greater than it it blah blah blah. Finally if no match is found it returns an error. It also returns an error if the test score is greater than `100`.

This method I presented is what I personally would do as I think it is more readable than a case statement. However if you still insist on using a case statement, you could try something like this:

```java
public static boolean isBetween(int x, int lower, int upper) {
  return lower <= x && x <= upper;
}

switch(Grade_Average)  {
 case isBetween(90, 100):
   System.out.println( " Your average test score is " + Grade_Average );
   System.out.println( "Your letter grade is an A." );
   break;
 case isBetween(80, 89):
   System.out.println( " Your average test score is " + Grade_Average );
   System.out.println( "Your letter grade is a B." );
   break;
 case isBetween(70, 79):
   System.out.println( " Your average test score is " + Grade_Average );
   System.out.println( "Your letter grade is a C." );
   break;     
 case isBetween(65, 69):
   System.out.println( " Your average test score is " + Grade_Average );
   System.out.println( "Your letter grade is a D." );
   break;
 case isBetween(0, 64):
   System.out.println( " Your average test score is " + Grade_Average );
   System.out.println( "Your letter grade is a F." );
   break;
default:
   System.out.println( " Invalid test score. ");
   break;
}
```

Comment: I changed case 79-70 to 70-79. Now the compiler shows no errors, but the only output I'm getting is the default output, which says " Invalid test score. "

Comment: **It is still not a range**. ``70-79`` is ``-9`` which is a score you will never match!